# Removing duplicates from Pandas Dataframe if the Duplicate value is in a different column on the next line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with a format that looks like this:

```
term_x  Intersections   term_y

boxers      1   briefs

briefs      1   boxers

babies      6   costumes

costumes    6   babies

babies     12   clothes

clothes    12   babies

babies      1   clothings

clothings   1   babies
```

This file has over several million rows. What I want to do is cut back on these redundant rows. Is there any way to use Pandas de-duping feature to eliminate these duplicates in a fast and Pythonic way? My current approach involves iteration over the entire dataframe, getting the values of the next line and then deleting the duplicate line but this has proven to be very slow:

```
row_iterator = duplicate_df_selfmerge.iterrows()
_, next = row_iterator.__next__()  # take first item from row_iterator
for index, row in row_iterator:
        if (row['term_x'] == next['term_y']) & (row['term_y'] == next['term_x']) & (row['Keyword'] == next['Keyword']):
            duplicate_df_selfmerge.drop(index, inplace=True)
        next = row
```

Comment: How do you define 'duplicate'? What's your desired output for your example?

Comment: Also your example has no `Keyword` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put those two columns together, sort the pairs, and then drop rows on those sorted pairs:

```
df['together'] = [','.join(x) for x in map(sorted, zip(df['term_x'], df['term_y']))]

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['together'])
Out[11]: 
   term_x  Intersections     term_y          together
0  boxers              1     briefs     boxers,briefs
2  babies              6   costumes   babies,costumes
4  babies             12    clothes    babies,clothes
6  babies              1  clothings  babies,clothings
```

Edit: You said time was a huge factor in this problem. Here are some timings comparing mine and Allen's solutions on a dataframe with 200,000 rows:

```
while df.shape[0] < 200000:
    df.append(df)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: str(sorted([x.term_x,x.term_y])), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.62 s per loop

%timeit [','.join(x) for x in map(sorted, zip(df['term_x'], df['term_y']))]
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

As you can see, my approach is more than 98% faster. `pandas.DataFrame.apply` is slow in many instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Intersections': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 12, 5: 12, 6: 1, 7: 1},
 'term_x': {0: 'boxers',1: 'briefs',2: 'babies',3: 'costumes',4: 'babies',
  5: 'clothes',6: 'babies',7: 'clothings'}, 'term_y': {0: 'briefs',1: 'boxers',
  2: 'costumes',3: 'babies',4: 'clothes',5: 'babies',6: 'clothings',7: 'babies'}})

#create a column to combine team_x and team_y in a sorted order
df['team_xy'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(sorted([x.term_x,x.term_y])), axis=1)
#drop duplicates on the combined fields.
df.drop_duplicates(subset='team_xy',inplace=True)

df
Out[916]: 
   Intersections  term_x     term_y                  team_xy
0              1  boxers     briefs     ['boxers', 'briefs']
2              6  babies   costumes   ['babies', 'costumes']
4             12  babies    clothes    ['babies', 'clothes']
6              1  babies  clothings  ['babies', 'clothings']
```